# How to get running applications in windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, cmd

How can I get the list of currently running applications or foreground processes in Windows?

I mean the applications that have a window for real. Not the background services/processes.
I want to access the same list a task manager shows when we open it.

Is there a way? 
Any type of solution is acceptable. Either a command or a .NET code or anything. I just want to get that list programmatically.

Is that even possible?

I tired tasklist but it gives me all the services and processes, even the background ones.

Is there any logic I could implement?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This may help:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process p in processes)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It will list all processes, even background services having title.