# C# Recognizing Open Applications on Combobox

Tags: c#, process, combobox

I am trying to create a basic macro recorder, which will work on any open application. So I have to specify application that my program will work on.

**How can i recognize and select open applications on visual studio's combobox tool?**

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470389/how-to-get-running-applications-in-windows

Comment: You want to get all the applications that are currently running?

Comment: remove Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] procArray;
Dictionary<string,int> applications = new Dictionary<string,int>();
procArray = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < procArray.Length; i++)
{
     if (procArray[i].MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
     {
            applications.Add(procArray[i].MainWindowTitle, procArray[i].Id);
     }
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> app in applications)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(app.Key);
}
```

This code will include only the processes that have open windows (if you run task managers in the tab "Applications" you will see those applications). The process Ids can be used to get the handles.

Comment: Thank you Sir. This is exactly what i am looking for and its perfectly working.^^