# How to get names of running applications?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I found on SO

[How to get running applications in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470389/how-to-get-running-applications-in-windows)

[How can I list all processes running in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648410/how-can-i-list-all-processes-running-in-windows)

I'm not in possibility to try does this also work on windows phone, and if not, is there way to get all names of running applications at the time, and if not, if there is some hackable way to achieve this, no matter if that doesn't pass store vertification?

I need this to track how much some application is in use.

Comment: In windows phone? hmm... didn't think about that before...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works the same on a windows phone but its worth a shot:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Now you can get a list of the processes with the Process.GetProcesses() method, as seen in this example:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
    Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

Some interesting properties of the Process object:

```
p.StartTime (Shows the time the process started)
p.TotalProcessorTime (Shows the amount of CPU time the process has taken)
p.Threads ( gives access to the collection of threads in the process)
```